# Suffix string starting at $i$

Tags: graph-theory, trees

$S$ is the string of characters:`TACGCGGT$`

For string S and each of the positions $i=1,2,\dots,9$ write down the suffix string starting at position $i$.

> What is the above question asking? For the following question I need to create the suffix tree, which I have done. But the above question seems to be asking me to simply write:

`TACGCGGT$`,`ACGCGGT$`,`CGCGGT$`,`GCGGT$`,`CGGT$`,`GGT$`,`GT$`,`T$`,`$`.

Surely that isn't the answer to the problem. What does it mean?

---

Alternatively: It could be asking me for

T: `ACGCGGT$`,`$`
A: `CGCGGT$`
C: `GCGGT$`,`GGT$`
G: `CGGT$`,`GT$`,`T$`
C: `GGT$`
$: ``

But that seems absurd, since it doesn't really feel like $i=1,2,\dots,9$ since we don't really do $i=6,7,8$, as they are already done.

---

The first way seems wrong since it would be too easy for a second year math course, especially for $8\%$ of the test's value...

Comment: That's what it sounds like.

Comment: Frankly, it really **does** look like your first interpretation is correct; I would have understood it the same way. Perhaps it is intended as a simple warm-up for the next question, so that if you do that one wrong, it will be clear if you just made a mistake or got no idea of what a suffix is :-)